# Forbidden PHP on Raspberry Pi

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up a basic RaspBerry Pi web server so I can install a personal Wiki to use it to store notes.

However, whenever I try to access the installation script it states:

> ### Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /dokuwiki/install.php on this server.

My Apache config file looks as follows:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
    Options Index FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
```

I can access phpMyAdmin no problem as well.

Comment: Is the apache user (www-data?) allowed to read that dir/file?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Output the result of `ls -ld /dokuwiki/` & `ls -l /dokuwiki/install.php`, and tell us which user the apache server runs as (if you don't know that either: a quick `ps aux | grep apache` would likely show it). Note: you may want to tell which OS you installed on your PI.

Comment: OS is Raspbian (Debian offshoot). My output is 
    `drwxrwxr-- 7 pi pi 4096 Jan  7 19:42 /var/www/dokuwiki`
  and   `rwxrwxr-- 1 pi pi 20108 Jan  7 19:36 /var/www/dokuwiki/install.php` respectively.

Comment: OK, so, `www-data` it is, but it would be allowed to read those files. No other `.htaccess` files in place there?

Comment: Have you done a 'Sudo chmod +x -R /var/www' ? (Minus the ' ' of course), this will give the files executable permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo chmod 775 /var/www/dokuwiki/install.php
```

This should make it executable, I had this problem when the PHP file wasn't executable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to recursively amend permissions using -R

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/
```

That should work.